# How can I Find/Replace part of a wildcard search in Notepad++

Tags: html, css, regex, background, notepad++

Simple Example.
When I'm editing CSS.
I want to Find all "backgrounds" regardless of the number sequence, so I'm using `.*`

*~~~Example:*
**Find** `background: #.*;`

> **(Found 4 Matches)**
>
> Line12: background: #111111;
>
> Line24: background: #222222;
>
> Line36: background: #333333;
>
> Line48: background: #444444;

"Found (#) of lines matching"
Great, works perfect!

**(The next part is the where I'm having trouble)**

Now I want to Replace, or in this case wrap all these lines with /*  */, without removing the individual numbers.
(To remove certain backgrounds, when I'm done editing the page.)

*~~~Example:*
**Replace With** `/* background: #.*; */`

> ***Doesn't give me this:***
>
> Line12: /* background: #111111; */
>
> Line24: /* background: #222222; */
>
> Line36: /* background: #333333; */
>
> Line48: /* background: #444444; */
>
> ***Instead, it give me this:***
>
> Line12: /* background: #.*; */
>
> Line24: /* background: #.*; */
>
> Line36: /* background: #.*; */
>
> Line48: /* background: #.*; */

I can't figure out how to keep the numbers (regardless of the variety of combinations) from changing in the code and only add /* ***around the code*** */

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your search to something little less reliant on having one space (say you hit tab on one or two).

```
(background:.*?;)
```

And for your replace, use:

```
/* \1 */
```

What you were failing to do was to capture the matched value to reuse in your replace regex. The () in the search will store in a parameter which can be used as \1.

Comment: That's good..exactly what I was looking for! I use multiple css files, one specifically for the editing so how can I reverse this and remove the /* */ ?

Comment: To reverse this, search for `\/\* (background:.*?;) \*\/` and replace with `\1` .. you don't have to worry about the number of spaces this time around, since the first search you specified one space after the /* and before the */. If you did want to worry about it you can further enhance your regex to handle possible multiple spaces.

Comment: phew's answer is inaccurate, but close. Since hex color codes go from 0 to F, you'll need to match on `[0-9A-Fa-f]+` inside the `()`

Comment: PERFECTION!! I was thinking the exact same thing about the number only system. Very nice man, saves me a lot of time!

Answer (score 6):

Search pattern: `background: #([0-9]+);`

Replace: `/* background: #\1 */`

([0-9]+) will match the numbers and save it in a group \1. You can re-use \1 in the "Replace" input.

Comment: Seems to work okay, but its not complete. Color schemes use numbers and letters from 0-F.

Comment: The first answer is a way better regex than mine, mine is very generic. You could extend it by the letters A through F like this: `(background: #[0-9a-fA-F]{6};?)` and use `/* \1 */` as replacement. It would also match `background: #DEDEDE`, hence the last CSS attribute in a CSS scope does not need a semicolon `;`, iirc. Also it would only match a colorcode that is 6 characters long. My answer was a quick one, it may be considered bad practice but I usually use lazy generic regex with a wide matching-range for issues like that, as long as they do their job.

Comment: Nice, that's good for other things too. I don't think best practices apply to use of editing with tools, just implementation of the code. Either way, I like both answers for different reasons. Thanks for the details, I'm sure I can use this somewhere along the line. My question was kind of generic in itself so it didn't need much depth for an answer. Very much appreciated..=D

Comment: Haha yeah, you'd probably spend a whole lot more time doing the regex than the implementation itself if you were to go the 'proper way' with issues like setting comments. The regex is far from complete, considering there can be other `background` values like `background: #00ff00 url('image.gif') no-repeat fixed center;` or `background: red`. Regex is a science on its own, very useful though. Np, have a good night!